# How do I get variable substitution to work with this sed command

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

I have this script:

```
PATTERN=xAB
dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=10 | sed "s/\x0/\${PATTERN}/g" > test_ab
hexdump -C test_ab
```

output I get is:

```
$ ./make_test 
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
10 bytes copied, 0.000147938 s, 67.6 kB/s
00000000  24 7b 50 41 54 54 45 52  4e 7d 24 7b 50 41 54 54  |${PATTERN}${PATT|
00000010  45 52 4e 7d 24 7b 50 41  54 54 45 52 4e 7d 24 7b  |ERN}${PATTERN}${|
00000020  50 41 54 54 45 52 4e 7d  24 7b 50 41 54 54 45 52  |PATTERN}${PATTER|
00000030  4e 7d 24 7b 50 41 54 54  45 52 4e 7d 24 7b 50 41  |N}${PATTERN}${PA|
00000040  54 54 45 52 4e 7d 24 7b  50 41 54 54 45 52 4e 7d  |TTERN}${PATTERN}|
00000050  24 7b 50 41 54 54 45 52  4e 7d 24 7b 50 41 54 54  |${PATTERN}${PATT|
00000060  45 52 4e 7d                                       |ERN}|
00000064
```

I want the file to be filled with 0xAB.

Comment: Hello. This is a Ubuntu OS support site. It does offer some help to bash when it applies to Ubuntu this is not a programming site. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Your variable is called `PATTERN1`, but you call it with `${PATTERN}`  (missing the 1).
- You escape the `$`, so your variable will **not** be substituted.
- Use [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) (`$'...'`) to assign the `0xAB` to the variable directly.

```bsh
$ PATTERN=$'\xAB'
$ dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=10 | sed "s/\x0/${PATTERN}/g"
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
10 bytes copied, 7,784e-05 s, 128 kB/s
����������
```

Alternatively, change your quoting:

```bsh
PATTERN=xAB
dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=10 | sed 's/\x0/\'"${PATTERN}"'/g'
```

or escape the backslash with a second backslash:

```bsh
PATTERN=xAB
dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=10 | sed "s/\x0/\\${PATTERN}/g"
```

Comment: sorry I was rushing,  I will redo - basically even with ${PATTERN1} - output still filled with ${PATTERN1}

Comment: you're still rushing, read my second point

Comment: Thanks - seen 2nd point

Comment: I thought that already, added that to my question.

Comment: improved a bit, you don't need to use ANSI-C quoting, you can also change your quoting of the `sed` command or escape the escape sign

Comment: lots of options - thank you

Answer (score 1):

For byte / character transliterations, you might want to use sed's `y` command rather than its `s` command:

```
$ PATTERN=xAB
$ dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=10 | sed "y/\x00/\\${PATTERN}/" | od -tx1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
0000000 ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
10 bytes copied, 0.0005294 s, 18.9 kB/s0000012
```

or perhaps more efficiently use `tr` in place of `sed` - you'd just need to convert from hex to octal:

```
$ PATTERN=xAB
$ dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=10 | tr '\000' "$(printf '\\%o' "${PATTERN/#/0}")" | od -tx1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
10 bytes copied, 0.0006387 s, 15.7 kB/s
0000000 ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
0000012
```

or

```
$ printf -v PATTERN '\\%o' 0xAB
$ dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=10 | tr '\000' "${PATTERN}" | od -tx1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
10 bytes copied, 0.000605 s, 16.5 kB/s
0000000 ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
0000012
```